# How can I get Mac Messages to stay in sync while the Mac is asleep or off?

Tags: messages

iOS 11.3, macOS Sierra

At night after about 9PM, my iMac is either asleep or powered off.  If during that time I receive any messages to my phone, they will not appear in the Mac message history when I wake it up or turn it on again.

I hate how my different devices (phone, tablet, laptop, desktop) all have different message histories.  Generally the phone is the only complete one since it pretty much never turns off.

[image]

Is it even possible to get a Mac to fetch recent messages that it missed?

Comment: What version of macOS are you using? My Mac occasionally gets a little bit behind, but has always caught up eventually.

Comment: Are you sure your phone is set up to use iCloud for messages?

Comment: Question updated to include OS versions.  As for "iCloud Messages" there is no such option on my Mac (Sierra).  Maybe this was added in High Sierra or later?  I see it on my Laptop running High Sierra so I suspect that's the case.

Comment: It works in El Capitan and newer.  As long as you have everything synced with iCloud, the messages will be in sync - they may take a few mins to catch up, but they do.

Comment: Well since there is no "iCloud Messages" option for Messages on Sierra... this doesn't seem to be the case.  And the messages NEVER "catch up".  Ever.  I can leave my machine on for days or weeks, they will never catch up.

Comment: What are your settings on the computer in Messages > Preferences > Accounts ? There is an iCloud checkbox there.

Comment: No, there is not.  Not in Sierra.  Unless I'm the only computer in the world running Sierra, that does not have it.  https://snag.gy/S4AR5E.jpg

Comment: Is the Apple ID that you're signed into on Message on Sierra the same as the one signed in on your iPhone/iPad?

Comment: Yep, I have only one.